# Odata returning 404 error with jquery get

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to configure some odata navigation and cannot see what the issue is here.

Config:

```
public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            var entitySetConfiguration = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Catalog>("Catalog");
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundCatalogItems);
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundColumns);
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundProcessor);
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundProcessorID);
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.RelationshipId);
            entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.CatalogConfigurationProperties);
            var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);

            config.EnableQuerySupport();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "apicontrollers/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
    }
```

Registration

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Helpers.DataAccess.DisposePDBUnitOfWork();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class CatalogController : EntitySetController<Catalog, int>
    {
        private readonly PDBCoreUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public CatalogController()
        {
            _unitOfWork = new PDBCoreUnitOfWork(0);
        }

        public override IQueryable<Catalog> Get()
        {
            return _unitOfWork.Repository<Catalog>().Query().Get();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var catalogApi = "/odata/Catalog";
        $.getJSON(catalogApi)
            .done(function(json) {
                console.log("Json data: " + json);
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
           });

</script>
```

When using fiddler localhost:port/odata returns 404 so does localhost:port/odata/Catalog

I must be missing some fundimentatl piece here.[Unit of work with oData](http://blog.longle.net/2013/10/09/upgrading-to-async-with-entity-framework-mvc-odata-asyncentitysetcontroller-kendo-ui-glimpse-generic-unit-of-work-repository-framework-v2-0/)

---

**UPDATE**
When I comment out the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ODataConfig.Register);
        }
```

And

```
public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            //var entitySetConfiguration = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Catalog>("Catalog");
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundCatalogItems);
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundColumns);
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundProcessor);
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.OutboundProcessorID);
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.RelationshipId);
            //entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.CatalogConfigurationProperties);
            var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model);

            config.EnableQuerySupport();

            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            //    );
        }
    }
```

Typeing localhost/port/odata returns:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://localhost:45837/odata">
<workspace>
<atom:title type="text">Default</atom:title>
</workspace>
</service>
```

But when i add `Catalog` after odata it throws 404 not found.  Still lost but making progress.

Comment: you configured the route to: `apicontrollers/...` not `odata/...`

Comment: I thought that section was to tell the routing which section your api was in, what happens if you have an api controller and MVC controller with the same name? Oh and the source code has it set up the way I do, with the routing pointing to his api folder.

Comment: No, it's a prefix before every route of WebAPI, you can change it to `odata` and it will work just fine.

Comment: Tried with `api/...` and `odata/...` and still receiving 404 error.  How does the routing know that my api controllers are in a path of `ApiControllers/CatalogController.cs`

Comment: Conflict is in the application start, after stripping out everything but the webapi it worked. Had to change the extention for the controller to `OdataController`

Comment: @ZachM. I couldn't clearly understand your last comment. Is the problem solved? Could you please past here the code snippet that solves it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to swap the order of registration

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ODataConfig.Register);
        }
```

And changed this

```
public class CatalogController : EntitySetController<Catalog, int>
    {
       ....
    }
```

To this

```
public class CatalogController : OdataController
    {
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

EntitySetController and AsyncEntitySetController are removed in new WebAPI version. You can always use "`public class {EntitySetName}Controller : ODataController` as your controller.

By the way, you can refer the following blog for new usage of WebApi 2.2 with OData V4:

[Getting started with ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)